# Detox Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm trying to run some e2e tests in my react-native up I'm using Detox but I keep getting the following error

```
1) "before all" hook:
     Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.


child_process.js:644
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/mocha e2e --opts e2e/mocha.opts       
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:641:13)
    at runMocha (/Users/Almog/Full-Time-Employment/Construction-Cloud/RnD/CCMobileApp/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:72:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Almog/Full-Time-Employment/Construction-Cloud/RnD/CCMobileApp/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:50:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to run it with `detox test --loglevel verbose` flag it may provide you additional information on what is the issue.