# Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: react-native, expo, e2e-testing, detox

I think the questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042947/detox-error-timeout-of-120000ms-exceeded-for-async-tests-and-hooks)) and ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638810/before-all-hook-error-timeout-of-2000ms-exceeded-for-async-tests-and-hooks)) were already asked but with no solution/answer to help.

I am trying to use Detox automation testing for a react-native app build using EXPO.
I did follow all the stated steps for implementing/ setting up of detox environment. So, I am using:

```
"expo": "^28.0.0",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "~0.55.2",

"mocha": "^5.2.0",
"detox": "^7.4.3",
"detox-expo-helpers": "^0.2.0",
```

have the following in **package.json**

```
"detox": {
"configurations": {
  "ios.sim": {
    "binaryPath": "bin/Exponent.app",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "name": "iPhone 7"
  }
 }
},
```

On Executing the detox test with the command:
//Removing old log
From which I assume that there is something I am missing in setup or configuration.
Also, the app.js has a simple view and a testID:

```
return (
  <View testID='welcome' style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
  </View>
);
```

and the test.spec.js has:

```
const { reloadApp } = require('detox-expo-helpers');

describe('Login Page Tests', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await reloadApp();
  });

  it('should have welcome message', async () => {
    try{
    await waitFor(element(by.id('welcome'))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(2000);
  }catch(e){
    console.log("Error is "+e);
  }
  });
```

I wasn't able to catch the error on the console though.
I did go through the synchronization page that detox has posted [here](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md)

So, any help is much appreciated.

I believe that there is a call back from the simulator device is missing.

**Update**:
Removing old log and adding the log with `--debug-synchronization 100` (as with 1000ms it did not print anything new) "There was this new error string being printed now with 100ms as the value."

```
>detoxDummy@0.1.0 e2e /Users/spusapati/detoxDummy
>detox test --debug-synchronization 100 --loglevel verbose --configuration ios.sim



detox-server info 15:44:14: server listening on localhost:49594...
detox verb ws onOpen [object Object]
detox verb ws send: {"type":"login","params":{"sessionId":"d86cfb45-0ae6-77b3-66ba-a26d217384a2","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"loginSuccess","params":{"sessionId":"d86cfb45-0ae6-77b3-66ba-a26d217384a2","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox verb ws  
detox verb 1: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl list -j 
detox verb 1: stdout: {
  "devicetypes" : [
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 4s",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s"
    },
    .....//Removing part of log due to character restrictions...
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 7",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 7 Plus",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7-Plus"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 8",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 8 Plus",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8-Plus"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone SE",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone X",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-X"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad 2",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Retina",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Air",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Air 2",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air-2"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad (5th generation)",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--5th-generation-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--10-5-inch-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple TV",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-1080p"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple TV 4K",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-4K"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple TV 4K (at 1080p)",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-1080p"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch - 38mm",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-38mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch - 42mm",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-42mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-2-42mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-3-38mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-3-42mm"
    }
  ],
  "runtimes" : [
    {
      "buildversion" : "15C107",
      "availability" : "(available)",
      "name" : "iOS 11.2",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-2",
      "version" : "11.2"
    },
    {
      "buildversion" : "15K104",
      "availability" : "(available)",
      "name" : "tvOS 11.2",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-11-2",
      "version" : "11.2"
    },
    {
      "buildversion" : "15S100",
      "availability" : "(available)",
      "name" : "watchOS 4.2",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-4-2",
      "version" : "4.2"
    }
  ],
  "devices" : {
    "iOS 11.2" : [
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 5s",
        "udid" : "8A1AFEE8-6500-4F58-BBE6-CE1848460816"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 6",
        "udid" : "C57DC2EB-64E1-400A-AE7F-BEFDEA718FF1"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 6 Plus",
        "udid" : "DDEAE34E-EF0C-454A-9F29-6D9E95AB980D"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 6s",
        "udid" : "6AEC2830-FDAC-4482-A6F0-379EF38D9C49"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 6s Plus",
        "udid" : "A4911598-9B1A-47AF-AEDD-F8151484CBED"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Booted",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 7",
        "udid" : "B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 7 Plus",
        "udid" : "5C559809-CCD2-432A-A631-A0F3E5BB451F"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 8",
        "udid" : "8A80B2B8-8E14-4138-8B54-B970F252D566"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 8 Plus",
        "udid" : "684EA650-B990-4296-A839-3D17D2FDE6C8"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone SE",
        "udid" : "C0E02C42-3C19-41EE-8AC5-2F6755D815B2"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone X",
        "udid" : "5EB1DD0B-EFE2-4E4B-8A1B-96B819CB95E6"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPad Air",
        "udid" : "68020EF5-7009-4667-BC33-657829D0582E"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPad Air 2",
        "udid" : "F3664198-F932-4603-AFCA-D851E6B7FEA7"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPad (5th generation)",
        "udid" : "87E9AF34-A170-4515-87E6-90BEF9C8C184"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
        "udid" : "65923279-A397-4534-87AD-7CD4FB6F4F36"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
        "udid" : "2B295643-98DF-431E-B250-09DEBA38FA91"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)",
        "udid" : "58767C90-9865-4E8E-A5A2-2A7F9E2939F5"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)",
        "udid" : "5C141E77-DE20-4A31-9C4F-0CF5DFC431CD"
      }
    ],
    "watchOS 4.2" : [
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "Apple Watch - 38mm",
        "udid" : "6B937036-3CCB-47C0-BC92-1DDA5128AC50"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "Apple Watch - 42mm",
        "udid" : "415D1DB5-0321-4B17-81EE-8B5FA529EA47"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm",
        "udid" : "E00C687A-599E-4CD7-89FD-9A121C5E5D63"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm",
        "udid" : "4E171AAD-0E2A-4C28-9AE7-0150906908D1"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm",
        "udid" : "C7CC45E7-9FAC-49E2-88D3-E4DEDFF1B9D6"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm",
        "udid" : "1C57E23D-7E7F-4271-823E-48AE32B0B2E9"
      }
    ],
    "tvOS 11.2" : [
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "Apple TV",
        "udid" : "038CFCB8-EF27-42E1-A50C-1BF2586593FF"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "Apple TV 4K",
        "udid" : "6979CD1D-B7C1-4F7D-88E9-4DD6644CA4B7"
      },
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "Apple TV 4K (at 1080p)",
        "udid" : "6FFEBBDC-DFC3-4602-9FAC-24CFB8EB8B4A"
      }
    ]
  },
  "pairs" : {
    "80C4BCAE-6CC0-454E-8EA6-7BD59E6D7416" : {
      "watch" : {
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm",
        "udid" : "C7CC45E7-9FAC-49E2-88D3-E4DEDFF1B9D6",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "phone" : {
        "name" : "iPhone 8",
        "udid" : "8A80B2B8-8E14-4138-8B54-B970F252D566",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "state" : "(active, disconnected)"
    },
    "5A5420EF-CEDC-4C46-ABE7-241BA961795E" : {
      "watch" : {
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm",
        "udid" : "4E171AAD-0E2A-4C28-9AE7-0150906908D1",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "phone" : {
        "name" : "iPhone 7 Plus",
        "udid" : "5C559809-CCD2-432A-A631-A0F3E5BB451F",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "state" : "(active, disconnected)"
    },
    "59986738-9BFD-472A-BE88-650CF7901AA8" : {
      "watch" : {
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm",
        "udid" : "E00C687A-599E-4CD7-89FD-9A121C5E5D63",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "phone" : {
        "name" : "iPhone 7",
        "udid" : "B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF",
        "state" : "Booted"
      },
      "state" : "(active, disconnected)"
    },
    "AAB8EE63-261D-4DB8-9963-9CB15B2B6373" : {
      "watch" : {
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm",
        "udid" : "1C57E23D-7E7F-4271-823E-48AE32B0B2E9",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "phone" : {
        "name" : "iPhone 8 Plus",
        "udid" : "684EA650-B990-4296-A839-3D17D2FDE6C8",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "state" : "(active, disconnected)"
    }
  }
}

detox verb 2: applesimutils --list --byType "iPhone 7" --byOS "11.2" 
detox info 2: Searching for device matching iPhone 7... 
detox verb 2: stdout: [
  {
    "deviceType" : {
      "name" : "iPhone 7",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7"
    },
    "state" : "Booted",
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "name" : "iPhone 7",
    "udid" : "B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF",
    "os" : {
      "version" : "11.2",
      "availability" : "(available)",
      "name" : "iOS 11.2",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-2",
      "buildversion" : "15C107"
    }
  }
]

detox verb 3: applesimutils --list --byId "B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF" 
detox verb 3: stdout: [
  {
    "deviceType" : {
      "name" : "iPhone 7",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7"
    },
    "state" : "Booted",
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "name" : "iPhone 7",
    "udid" : "B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF",
    "os" : {
      "version" : "11.2",
      "availability" : "(available)",
      "name" : "iOS 11.2",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-2",
      "buildversion" : "15C107"
    }
  }
]

detox verb 4: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF host.exp.Exponent 
detox info 4: Uninstalling host.exp.Exponent... 
detox info 4: host.exp.Exponent uninstalled 
detox verb 5: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF "/Users/spusapati/detoxDummy/bin/Exponent.app" 
detox info 5: Installing /Users/spusapati/detoxDummy/bin/Exponent.app... 
detox info 5: /Users/spusapati/detoxDummy/bin/Exponent.app installed 
detox verb 6: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF host.exp.Exponent 
detox info 6: Terminating host.exp.Exponent... 
detox info 6: host.exp.Exponent terminated 
detox verb 7: /bin/cat /dev/null >$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err && SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/spusapati/Library/Detox/ios/b92b7e2e1bf57e1d79704e793f861df2bbbce00e/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out --stderr=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF host.exp.Exponent --args -detoxServer ws://localhost:49594 -detoxSessionId d86cfb45-0ae6-77b3-66ba-a26d217384a2 
detox info 7: Launching host.exp.Exponent... 
detox verb 7: stdout: host.exp.Exponent: 73658

detox info 7: host.exp.Exponent launched. The stdout and stderr logs were recreated, you can watch them with:
        tail -F $HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.{out,err} 
detox verb ws send: {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"ready","messageId":-1000,"params":{}}
detox verb ws  
  Login Page Tests
detox verb 8: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF host.exp.Exponent 
detox info 8: Terminating host.exp.Exponent... 
detox info 8: host.exp.Exponent terminated 
detox verb 9: /bin/cat /dev/null >$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err && SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/spusapati/Library/Detox/ios/b92b7e2e1bf57e1d79704e793f861df2bbbce00e/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out --stderr=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF host.exp.Exponent --args -detoxServer ws://localhost:49594 -detoxSessionId d86cfb45-0ae6-77b3-66ba-a26d217384a2 -EXKernelDisableNuxDefaultsKey true -detoxURLOverride exp://wz-yd7.spusapati.detoxdummy.exp.direct:80 -detoxSourceAppOverride host.exp.exponent 
detox info 9: Launching host.exp.Exponent... 
detox verb 9: stdout: host.exp.Exponent: 73671

detox info 9: host.exp.Exponent launched. The stdout and stderr logs were recreated, you can watch them with:
        tail -F $HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B245E144-AA15-4647-8CBE-0D8A927188FF/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.{out,err} 
detox verb ws send: {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"AppWillTerminateWithError","messageId":-10000,"params":{"threadNumber":1,"errorDetails":"*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: key cannot be nil\n(\n\t0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c8fa12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171\n\t1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011b246f41 objc_exception_throw + 48\n\t2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c93a0cc _CFThrowFormattedException + 194\n\t3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c99faba -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] + 970\n\t4   Exponent                            0x000000010f0d2c6e -[EXErrorRecoveryManager setError:forExperienceId:] + 259\n\t5   Exponent                            0x000000010f04d92a -[EXReactAppManager _handleJavaScriptLoadEvent:] + 634\n\t6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c895eac __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12\n\t7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c895daa _CFXRegistrationPost + 442\n\t8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c895af2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50\n\t9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c857792 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826\n\t10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c85690c _CFXNotificationPost + 652\n\t11  Foundation                          0x0000000115b158f2 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66\n\t12  Exponent                            0x000000010fbbcd3f __37-[ABI27_0_0RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke + 417\n\t13  EarlGrey                            0x000000013053eb94 __60-[GREYDispatchQueueTracker grey_dispatchAsyncCallWithBlock:]_block_invoke + 36\n\t14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011d83b177 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12\n\t15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011d83c1ba _dispatch_client_callout + 8\n\t16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011d8463a4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1260\n\t17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c8bce39 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9\n\t18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c881462 __CFRunLoopRun + 2402\n\t19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c880889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409\n\t20  EarlGrey                            0x000000013055dd43 -[GREYRunLoopSpinner grey_drainRunLoopInActiveModeAndCheckCondition:forTime:] + 627\n\t21  EarlGrey                            0x000000013055d6ac -[GREYRunLoopSpinner spinWithStopConditionBlock:] + 588\n\t22  EarlGrey                            0x00000001305ac24e -[GREYUIThreadExecutor executeSyncWithTimeout:block:error:] + 1422\n\t23  EarlGrey                            0x00000001305abc71 -[GREYUIThreadExecutor executeSync:error:] + 273\n\t24  Detox                               0x00000001134ce30d __45-[EarlGreyImpl(Detox) detox_safeExecuteSync:]_block_invoke + 135\n\t25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c89d05c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12\n\t26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c88183b __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 203\n\t27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c881014 __CFRunLoopRun + 1300\n\t28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c880889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409\n\t29  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011ddb69c6 GSEventRunModal + 62\n\t30  UIKit                               0x00000001186fb5d6 UIApplicationMain + 159\n\t31  Detox                               0x00000001134d0f5e __WX_UIApplicationMain + 197\n\t32  Exponent                            0x000000010f0f697b main + 80\n\t33  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011d8b0d81 start + 1\n)","queueName":"com.apple.main-thread"}}
detox verb ws  
    1) "before each" hook for "should have welcome screen"

  0 passing (18s)
  1 failing

  1) Login Page Tests
       "before each" hook for "should have welcome screen":
     Error: the string "*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: key cannot be nil\n(\n\t0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c8fa12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171\n\t1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011b246f41 objc_exception_throw + 48\n\t2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c93a0cc _CFThrowFormattedException + 194\n\t3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c99faba -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] + 970\n\t4   Exponent                            0x000000010f0d2c6e -[EXErrorRecoveryManager setError:forExperienceId:] + 259\n\t5   Exponent                            0x000000010f04d92a -[EXReactAppManager _handleJavaScriptLoadEvent:] + 634\n\t6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c895eac __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12\n\t7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c895daa _CFXRegistrationPost + 442\n\t8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c895af2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50\n\t9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c857792 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826\n\t10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c85690c _CFXNotificationPost + 652\n\t11  Foundation                          0x0000000115b158f2 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66\n\t12  Exponent                            0x000000010fbbcd3f __37-[ABI27_0_0RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke + 417\n\t13  EarlGrey                            0x000000013053eb94 __60-[GREYDispatchQueueTracker grey_dispatchAsyncCallWithBlock:]_block_invoke + 36\n\t14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011d83b177 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12\n\t15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011d83c1ba _dispatch_client_callout + 8\n\t16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011d8463a4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1260\n\t17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c8bce39 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9\n\t18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c881462 __CFRunLoopRun + 2402\n\t19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c880889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409\n\t20  EarlGrey                            0x000000013055dd43 -[GREYRunLoopSpinner grey_drainRunLoopInActiveModeAndCheckCondition:forTime:] + 627\n\t21  EarlGrey                            0x000000013055d6ac -[GREYRunLoopSpinner spinWithStopConditionBlock:] + 588\n\t22  EarlGrey                            0x00000001305ac24e -[GREYUIThreadExecutor executeSyncWithTimeout:block:error:] + 1422\n\t23  EarlGrey                            0x00000001305abc71 -[GREYUIThreadExecutor executeSync:error:] + 273\n\t24  Detox                               0x00000001134ce30d __45-[EarlGreyImpl(Detox) detox_safeExecuteSync:]_block_invoke + 135\n\t25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c89d05c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12\n\t26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c88183b __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 203\n\t27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c881014 __CFRunLoopRun + 1300\n\t28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c880889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409\n\t29  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011ddb69c6 GSEventRunModal + 62\n\t30  UIKit                               0x00000001186fb5d6 UIApplicationMain + 159\n\t31  Detox                               0x00000001134d0f5e __WX_UIApplicationMain + 197\n\t32  Exponent                            0x000000010f0f697b main + 80\n\t33  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011d8b0d81 start + 1\n)" was thrown, throw an Error :)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)




child_process.js:644
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/mocha e2e --opts e2e/mocha.opts --configuration ios.sim --loglevel verbose   --debug-synchronization 100 --grep :android: --invert  
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:641:13)
    at runMocha (/Users/spusapati/detoxDummy/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:114:6)
    at run (/Users/spusapati/detoxDummy/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:75:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/spusapati/detoxDummy/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:181:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! detoxDummy@0.1.0 e2e: `detox test --debug-synchronization 100 --loglevel verbose --configuration ios.sim`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the detoxDummy@0.1.0 e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/spusapati/.npm/_logs/2018-06-27T22_44_32_576Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Also, I can see the screen load and able to see the message, but still the detox test fails.

Comment: Use --debug-synchronization and post the full log again

Comment: I just identified that from Detox@7.3.0, I am unable to integrate with expo.
The previous version i.e. Detox@7.2.0 worked like a charm.

@Rotemmiz will be doing that now.

Comment: @Rotemmiz I did update the log as requested do check it out.